# iOS Obj-C convert byte array to plist to string

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging

Argh, I'm going nuts.

I've got the following function which I am trying to log with a custom logger

```
CFWriteStreamWrite(CFWriteStreamRef stream, const UInt8 *buffer,
    CFIndex bufferLength) {

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length: bufferLength]; 


NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSString * str = (NSString*)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                      propertyListFromData:data
                                      mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                      format:&format
                                      errorDescription:&errorDesc];


custom_log(CF, "CFURLCreateWithString: %s", str);
}
```

When I use my custom logger I get rubbish output

```
CFURLCreateWithString: <       °3€
```

But when using NSLog, everything works fine,

```
Feb 10 00:36:39: {
        bundleID = "com.test.testapp";
        pid = 2852;
    }
```

Custom Logger

```
EXPORT void custom_log(unsigned int facility, const char *msg, ...) {
if (minLogLevel <= INFO) {
    char *msgBuffer;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, msg);
    vasprintf(&msgBuffer, msg, args);
    va_end(args);

    dispatch_async(logQueue, ^{
        write(facility, INFO, msgBuffer);
    });
}
}
```

Please tell me where I'm going wrong, I have spent the past 3 hours trying to convert to different data types. No luck.

Also, is it possible to get the output from NSLog into a string and then I'll just pass it to my logger instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems that you might be experiencing here is that `NSString` is not the same as the `c_str` that your `vasprintf` method is likely expecting to substitute for `%s`.

To compound this issue, I'm pretty sure you can't directly convert `NSPropertyListSerialization` to `NSString`, though I didn't test it myself. You might be looking for such an alternative instead:

```
NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSPropertyListSerialization
                                  propertyListFromData:data
                                  mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                  format:&format
                                  errorDescription:&errorDesc]];


custom_log(CF, "CFURLCreateWithString: %s", [str UTF8String]);
```

Of course, since you're already compositing a string, why not just do it all in the same place?

```
NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CFURLCreateWithString: %@", [NSPropertyListSerialization
                                  propertyListFromData:data
                                  mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                  format:&format
                                  errorDescription:&errorDesc]];


custom_log(CF, [str UTF8String]);
```

---

As a fun side project, you might consider doing something like this in your main.mm. Replace `stderr` with `stdout` if you want more than just error stuff:

```
#if COPY_NSLOG_TO_CUSTOM
typedef int (*MyStdWriter)(void *, const char *, int);
static MyStdWriter _oldStdWrite;
int __customStderrWrite(void *inFD, const char *buffer, int size) {
  if (minLogLevel <= INFO) {
    // write to your custom stream here.
  }
  return _oldStdWrite(inFD, buffer, size);
}

void __copyNSLogToCustom(void) {
  _oldStdWrite = stderr->_write;
  stderr->_write = __customStderrWrite;
}
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
#if COPY_NSLOG_TO_CUSTOM
  __copyNSLogToCustom();
#endif
// ...
}
```

Comment: OH! My friend! Thank you SO VERY MUCH! You have saved me so much headache! Thank you thank you